# Set Views exposed filter to ignore case

Tags: views

I have a view which uses an exposed filter to let the user filter the results via keyword (in other words it behaves like a text search).  The actual field is implemented using views_fields_combine module, but I assume this issues applies to any field which contains text.  The problem I have is that the filter only works correctly if the case of the "search" text matches the content in the field.

For example if the field contains "Cool Capacitors" and the user types "Cool" in the exposed filter then there will be a resulting match.  But it the user types "cool" then the filter will not find any matching results.

I would like to know if there is a method of making the exposed filter ignore the case when making matches.  Strangely enough I have not been able to find any information on this on the internet.  I am wondering if I am try to do something that exposed filters was not designed to do?  Perhaps there is some alternative method I could consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you directly or get you started in the right direction -  [Combine fields filter case-sensitive search](https://drupal.org/node/1805272)